# Problems retrrieving data from serial device with python Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, serial-port, raspberry-pi

i have a solenoid control hardware that I am trying to use for an Access system, according to the manual of the device i am sending the command to the device and tri to get the status but i am only receiving blank lines.

the command to know the estatus of the ports is the following:

4. Read the lock status command(The feedback of the door switch status)
   Start   plate address   Lock address   Command    Check code (XOR)
   0X80     0X01 – 0XF            0X00-32       0X33        XX
   The lock address is 0X00, return the status of all of the locks, if it’s not 0, then it will back to this lock status.

   eg:
   a.  Return back to the status of lock 1
   eg: Upper computer send 0X80  0X01   0X01  0X33  0XB2 (hexadecimal),
   return
   Command   plate address   Lock address   Status    Check cod
     0X80        0X01            0X01         0X11      0X91  (Lock Open)
     0X80        0X01            0X01         0X00      0X80  (Lock Close
   b. Return back to the status of all of the locks:

eg: Host machine send 0X80  0X01   0X00  0X33  0XB2 (hexadecimal),return
Start  plate address  Status1  Status2  Status3  Status4  Status5  Status6 Status7

Command   Check cod
0X80  0X01  0XFF  0XFF  0XFF  0XFF  0XFF  0XFF  0XFF  0X33  0XXX

Status: From status 1 to Status 7, high to low, the corresponding lock is 1-50.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# based on tutorials:
#   http://www.roman10.net/serial-port-communication-in-python/
#   http://www.brettdangerfield.com/post/raspberrypi_tempature_monitor_project/

import serial, time

SERIALPORT = "/dev/ttyUSB0"
BAUDRATE = 9600

ser = serial.Serial(SERIALPORT, BAUDRATE)

ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS #number of bits per bytes

ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE #set parity check: no parity

ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE #number of stop bits

#ser.timeout = None          #block read

#ser.timeout = 0             #non-block read

ser.timeout = 2              #timeout block read

ser.xonxoff = False     #disable software flow control

ser.rtscts = False     #disable hardware (RTS/CTS) flow control

ser.dsrdtr = False       #disable hardware (DSR/DTR) flow control

ser.writeTimeout = 0     #timeout for write

print 'Starting Up Serial Monitor'

if ser.isOpen():

    try:
        ser.flushInput() #flush input buffer, discarding all its contents
        ser.flushOutput()#flush output buffer, aborting current output

        ser.write (serial.to_bytes([0X80,0X01,0X33,0XB2]))
        print("write data: 0X80,0X01,0X33,0XB2")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        numberOfLine = 0

        while True:

            response = ser.readline()
            print("read data: " + response)

            numberOfLine = numberOfLine + 1
            if (numberOfLine >= 8):
                break

        ser.close()

    except Exception, e:
        print "error communicating...: " + str(e)

else:
    print "cannot open serial port "
```

And this is my result:

read data:
read data:
read data:
read data:
read data:
read data:
read data:
read data:

Can you please help me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You are using ` readline` but there is no `\n` at the end of your `ser.write(...` Data.

Comment: Thanks for your help @stovfl, can you please help me with the syntax, i'am new with Python programming so i'm not pretty sure if i undertand your suggestion, thanks. do you mean: ` ser.write (serial.to_bytes([0X80,0X01,0X33,0XB2\n])) `

Answer (score 0):

> **Comment** ...  document: link

1. Your command `[0x80,0x01,0x33,0xB2]` **is wrong**.
   use

   ```
   ser.write ([0x80, 0x01, 0x01, 0x33, 0xB2])
   ```

   or

   ```
   ser.write ([0x80, 0x01, 0x00, 0x33, 0xB2])
   ```
2. Let's check if `pySerial` see your Serial Port and the *Solenoid Control Hardware*.
   Execute the following and examine the output:

   ```
   python -m serial.tools.list_ports
   ```
3. Remove **ALL** settings between

   ```
   ser.bytesize
   ...
   ser.writeTimeout
   ```

   use **defaults** with **only** this code:

   ```
   ser = serial.Serial(SERIALPORT)
   ```

---

Change to the following:

```
    ser.write ([0x80, 0x01, 0x00, 0x33, 0xB2])
```

You already have `binary` Data, therefore no encoding required.
Read [pySerial 3.0 documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#module-functions-and-attributes)
`serial.to_bytes(sequence)`

I'm unsure about your command, your Question's description is somewhat unclear.
Do you have a public link to the Documentation of *Solenoid Control Hardware*.

Comment: I can share with you the communication protocol sent by the HW manufacturer

Comment: Here is the document:
[link](http://www.clasifica24.com/sites/default/files/docs/controller-lock.txt)

Comment: @OscarSilva: Updated Answer